# Twilio Programmable Voice: Avoid the "We're sorry, an application error has occurred message"

Tags: twilio

Has anyone successfully stopped this message from being sent out as a phone call?  If there is an issue retrieving the message to be played, for whatever reason, we don't want our recipients called giving them this message.  There ought to be a way to avoid sending the call and get the error back via the StatusCallback method or if unavailable just post it in the logs.  Twilio support has been horrible in answering my question so I am hoping that someone in the community has had some experience with this.  They are telling me that I have to stop the call myself somehow but the only way I know there is an issue is when I receive the failed status, by then it's too late to stop the call.  Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I found this, but there may be certain failures that it doesn't address. Worth testing it in your use case.

Availability and Reliability

[Custom Error Message](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/security/availability-reliability#custom-error-message)

--

**Custom Error Message**

Problem: You do not want your callers to hear the default Twilio application error message.

Solution: Create an error TwiML document to  or  a custom error message. Configure the Voice Fallback URL for your phone number to point at this document's URL. If Twilio encounters a fatal error, callers will hear your custom failure message instead of Twilio's.